# ChunkedEncodingError while making an API query

Tags: python, api, python-requests

This is a small API request that is throwing me a `requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError`

```
import requests

def categories_list():   
    categories = []
    response = requests.get("https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/categories&json=1")        
    data = response.json()
    i = 0        
    for category in data["tags"]:
        if category["products"] >= 1200:
            name = category["name"]
            categories.append(name)
            i += 1                

    print("It's ok, imported %s" % i)

categories_list()
```

Error code:

```
 File "exception.py", line 18, in <module>
    categories_list()
  File "exception.py", line 6, in categories_list
    response = requests.get("https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/categories&json=1")        
  File "/home/pi/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 683, in send
    r.content
  File "/home/pi/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 829, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/home/pi/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 754, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(3573 bytes read, 6667 more expected)', IncompleteRead(3573 bytes read, 6667 more expected))
```

Could it be possibly my internet connection? Similar queries worked for me yesterday...